# as x goes to infinity, f(x) go to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis

i've been learning about continuity and limit of functions. I've learnt how about things like $f(x)$ approaching $L$ as $x$ approach $a$. 
And I was wondering, is there a definition for $f(x)$ going to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity? How would you express that mathematically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As follows:

$$
\mathrm{lim}_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = +\infty \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \text{for all} \quad M>0 \quad \text{there exists} \quad \delta > 0 \quad \text{such that, if}\quad x > \delta \ , \quad \text{then} \quad f(x) > M \ .
$$

See also [Wikipedia on limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function) .